# HTACCESS redirect if pattern found in URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have the URL http://www.mydomain.com/firstdir/seconddir/file.php or the URL http://www.mydomain.com/firstdir/file.php and some others. Within the existing .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

I 'd like to have a redirect for any URL to the page XY, if the pattern *firstdir* is in the URL path.

Whenever I tried to build in any rewriteCond, the whole website is redirected... 
Thanky for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned code.

```
RewriteRule ^firstdir/([^/\.]+)/?$ XY.php [L]
```

So, the full code will be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^firstdir/([^/\.]+)/?$ XY.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```